# Highliget row in tkinter treeview

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a treeView that load its row from data in combobox,
after that, I wont that the row in the treeView that contains the selected value in the combobox will be highlighted.
this is a simple code for what I mean:

```
selected_symbol = self.combo.get()
    children = self.tree.get_children()
    for item in children:
        data = self.tree.item(item)
        if selected_symbol == self.tree.item(item, 'text'):
            self.tree.tag_configure('MRO', background="yellow")


def build_tree():
    tree.heading('#0', text='colume 0')
    tree.heading('#1', text='colume 1')
    tree.heading('#2', text='colume 2')
    tree.heading('#3', text='colume 3')

    tree.column('#0')
    tree.column('#1')
    tree.column('#2')
    tree.grid(row=2, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
    build_tree_row()


def build_tree_row():
    for data in combo["values"]:
        tree.insert('', 'end', text=data,
                    values="disable", tag=data))


def manege_symbol_select(event):
    print(combo.get())
    highlight_selected_row()


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(int(window.winfo_screenwidth() / 2), int(window.winfo_screenheight() / 2)))
tree = Treeview(window, columns=("status", 'symbol', 'inventory'))
combo = Combobox(window, values=['row1', 'row2', 'row2'])
combo.current(0)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", manege_symbol_select)
combo.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='s')
build_tree()
window.mainloop()
```

in function manege_symbol_select there is a function call to highlite_selected_row and this is the function I wont to implement

**EDIT** added the implementation of highlight_selected_row  tried with tags and tag config but the bg not working

Comment: All of the treeview methods necessary to highlight a row are documented, but it doesn't look like you've tried any of them.

Comment: where could I find the official documentation? i tried looking for it. and also i added my attempt by using tag_configure

Comment: Within a python interpreter with ttk imported you can do `print(help(ttk.Treeview))`. Another good source for help is https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html. The official documentation is here, though it's not comprehensive: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html. The canonical documentation written for tcl/tk is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm. The previously mentioned official documentation gives advice on how to translate the tcl/tk documentation into python.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you vare match, and can you see why is my program dosent work?